# Is my algebra alright, despite obtaining a different output from Matlab

Tags: algebra-precalculus, matlab

I am going through previous algebra exercises that I had performed from a textbook in Matlab.

However, although I am certain that my results are correct, Matlab is throwing up different answers to mine.

Examples of some of these questions are:

1. $$ 16x^2 - 40xy + 25y^2 = 0$$

For this, I get factors of $$ (4x - 5y)^2 = 0$$

2. $$ 5x^2 + 13x + 6 = 0$$

For this, I get factors of $$ (5x + 3)(x + 2) = 0$$

3. $$ 2x^2 - 11x + 12 = 0$$

For that, I get factors of $$ (2x - 3)(x - 4) = 0$$

And the results produced by Matlab are shown below:

[image: Results produced by Matlab]

Ultimately, what I am seeking is just confirmation that my answers are correct and that Matlab is just displaying other possible solutions!

Comment: When I try to solve the second equation in MATLAB I get answers which agree with yours.  I'm not sure where it's getting $3/2$ and $9/20$.

Comment: That makes two of us!! Any luck on the third? :)

Comment: My MATLAB is also agreeing with you for the third equation, maybe it's a bug with `solve`?

Comment: Many thanks. Maybe, I'm working the program too hard! :)

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I am using R2013

Comment: Might be an issue with that version.  It's working fine with my R2016b.

Comment: You might try the online version: https://matlab.mathworks.com/ . It's apparently limited in some ways (I switched tabs, and when I went back my prior work was gone), but at least it's up to date.

Comment: Thanks @DMcMor. I'll give the program a break for now and see if I obtain the correct result when I try again later!

Comment: @JohnHughes I don't really think that the version is an issue. But, I'll give your suggestion a try if the performance of this version doesn't improve!

Comment: @aLoHa - you might also get a more of a response if you ask this on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead.  This seems like more of a MATLAB question than a mathematics question.

Comment: Thanks. Will do so, going forward!!

Answer (score 2):

Your algebra is simply wrong for part 1.

$$
(3x-4)(2y+5) = 6xy - 8y + 15x - 20
$$
which is not at all the same as $$16^2−40+25^2$$.

In fact, $16^2−40xy+25^2 = 0$ actually factors as
$$
(4x - 5y)^2 = 0
$$
for which any pair $(x,y) = (a, -\frac{5}{4}a)$ is a solution.

I don't understand Matlab's answer that $y$ is $0$ or $0$, however.

Part 2: Your algebra is right here, but Matlab's answer is baffling. No positive value of $x$ can yield a root of that equation, because all three terms are positive, and hence cannot sum to zero. Perhaps "solve" doesn't work the way you (and I) may think it does. Then again, when I tried running it, Matlab gave the answers $-2, -3/5$. Did you remember to declare `x` symbolic with `sym x`?

Comment: My bad. I attributed another answer to the question. My answer was indeed the same as yours. I will re-edit the question. Thanks for the spot!